# Use a native SQL subquery within a HQL query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, subquery, hql

I would want to create a HQL query with a native SQL subquery. It's possible to use a HQL subquery within a HQL query but what about a native SQL subquery within a HQl query ? 
Cause, in hibernate, we use session.createQuery to create a HQL query and session.createSQLQuery to create a native SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to mix both HQL and SQL. You can't. Execute them separately and use it with one another. That is the only way.

Comment: Ok, but how exactly ? For example, I have the following query : session.createQuery("select...inner join(query1)"). With query1 being a native SQL query. Can I code the query 1 alone, name it then reference it in my main HQL query ?

Comment: @user3490028 Exactly. Using the query result in main query. No other work around so far.